# #200 the user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi every one i have seen lots of solution but i am not able to get the point

I am developing an app to  updatestatus on button click Its working fine with test user

and i have generate hash key from facebook api guide as following

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.example.helpme", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.e("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

and whenever i login from another account #200 the user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

please help me its not working after live too...

Comment: is you app on facebook is on production status?

Comment: production status?? i am not getting your point my app is showing online availble to all users..

Comment: authorize with publish_actions and make sure you try with an app admin

Comment: yes. there is a problem in hash key generation when i am generating it through openssl commond prompt it is differ from using code key hash

Comment: its working fine with test user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if your code is working for a test user then do not touch the code of sharing on facebook.

Go on facebook app and properlly request for publish_action ofter live your app on google play it will be granted by facebook follow this (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/**your_app_id**/review-status/)!
please set your app_id at the place of **Your_app_id**